# Getting errors when using rsync in a script, but not when using the line directly in the command line

Tags: bash, rsync

I'm trying to set up rsync to run backups from my Unraid shares to external drives mounted to the Unraid server.

I have different folders in different shares that I want backed up to different folders on different external drives.
I.e:

1. /share1/folder1/ should be synced to /externalDisk1/folder1/
2. /share1/folder2/ should be synced to /externalDisk2/folder1/
   etc.

I have eight of these jobs, all together.
The idea is to run these as a cron job every night, and so I wrote them all down in a bash script.

Running the rsync lines one by one, or even as  "job1; job2.." in the command line works great, however, calling them from "backup.sh" returns errors.

The script (with only one rsync line as an example):

```
#!/bin/sh
rsync -rtvh --progress /mnt/user/share1/folder1/ /mnt/disks/externalDrive1/Folder1/
```

returns

```
sending incremental file list
rsync: [Receiver] mkdir "/mnt/disks/externalDisk1/Folder1/\#015" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at main.c(784) [Receiver=3.2.3]
rsync: [sender] write error: Broken pipe (32)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at io.c(823) [sender=3.2.3]
```

Any suggestions on what's going on and how to fix this?

Comment: Are you running the script from `cron`? That could be the relevant difference.

Comment: At the moment I've only just tried running it from the command line (bash backup.sh)

Comment: In that case there's absolutely no reason why it would work differently.

Comment: BTW, why do you use `bash backup.sh` rather than `sh backup.sh` so it matches the shebang line? It doesn't currently have an code that behaves differently, but you might add it in the future.

Comment: How strange.. I'm not really a guy that spends a lot of time in the command line, and I've just learned that I could run .sh scripts using bash <scriptname>, so that's what I've always done. I'll give sh a try! Cheers

Comment: Removing the #!/bin/sh from the top of the script clears out two of the error lines. I'm now left with

sending incremental file list
rsync: [Receiver] mkdir "/mnt/disks/externalDisk1/Folder1/\#015" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at main.c(784) [Receiver=3.2.3]

Comment: The `#!` line is totally ignored when you use `bash backup.sh` (it's just a comment as far as the shell is concerned), so removing it can't possibly make any difference. I think what you're actually seeing is some kind of transient error, and it's just coincidence that it happens when you run the command from a script.

Answer (score 0):

Running the script through the CA User Scripts plug-in makes it run perfectly. It's a work-around, if nothing else :)